# Programming for IOS, how is it done?

Tags: scripting, cisco, cisco-ios

On my Cisco 800 router in my home, I am seeing something called the "IOS", I know it is Internetwork Operating System. But in the world of programming is this a language like Python, Ruby, Java, etc? If you wanted to write a script that runs on the router itself, not having another computer open a socket go to the device and running some shell command. Something as simple as broadcast attached devices to my router every 60 minutes. What are we talking here for the actual program that is used to write an IOS?

Comment: @MatteoItalia did you have a look at the page? On the top of the page there is a box "Meanings of iOS", where different meanings of this phrase are listed, including Apple IOS and Cisco and some others

Comment: @gefei - first line `iOS is a mobile operating system developed by Apple Inc.` - and each line after that refers to the same.  You might be able to scroll and eventually find some mention of Cisco, but that's not the point of a LMGTFY response.

Comment: @KevinDTimm sorry, I usually read more than one line of a page. I think that's pretty bad. However, I never said I meant to give an LMGTFY response.

Comment: @gefei - on my monitor, the first mention of the word `Cisco` is below the first screen of information, the 10th search result.  That doesn't include the box with 7 other pieces of information (that also do not include `Cisco`.  Note too that the OP already knows what IOS stands for, but doesn't know anything about IOS programming, which your link provides no information about.

Comment: @KevinDTimm On my monitor I see the box of "meanings of ios" right on the top, and in the box, under "computing", Cisco is the first item. Anyway, I don't think this discussion is going to be helpful. I am removing my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a program that talks to your router, search for a program called `expect` - it will serve you well. It uses the serial port of the router to do so.

In answer to your basic question, no, you can't write a program that is downloaded to a router that will run on it.

Comment: TCL and kron should work on 800 series Cisco routers, but you don't write a 'new IOS'.